# How would I show text inside a span tag when hovering over a different element?

Tags: css, hover, html

I have a webpage set up that has multiple DIV tags in a grid like table. I would like to know if it's possible by using CSS to show text when mousing over a DIV or IMG or A tag. I could use any of those 3 to make it happen since one of my DIV tags holds just the IMG which is also a hyperlink to a new page. A sample of one of my rows in my page is setup kinda like this:

```
    <div class="Home-06">
    <a href="image1link.html">
    <img src="images/image1.jpg" width="250" height="250" alt="" 
        style="border-width: 0px"></a>
</div>
<div class="Home-07">
    <span>Text for Image 1</span><span>Text for Image 2</span>
</div>
<div class="Home-08">
    <a href="image2link.html">
    <img src="images/image2.jpg" width="250" height="250" alt="" 
        style="border-width: 0px"></a>
</div>
```

I'd like to make the middle DIV "Home-07" with my span tags display different text when hovering over "Home-06" and "Home-08".

My CSS:

```
div.Home-06 {
position:absolute;
left:102px;
top:450px;
width:250px;
height:250px;
}
div.Home-07 {
position:absolute;
left:352px;
top:450px;
width:320px;
height:250px;
background-color:#000000;
}
div.Home-08 {
position:absolute;
left:672px;
top:450px;
width:250px;
height:250px;
}
```

Comment: Please read on how to use Markdown for posting. HTML code would be much more clearer to read.

Comment: write the actual HTML. Highlight it. Then press CTRL+k

Comment: I pasted in a sample of my html page. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is if the span is contained within the element that you are hovering over, so for example:

```
<div class="alwaysshowme">
    <p>
        I can always be seen [hover over me!]
        <span class="showmeonhover"><br />I can only be seen on hover...</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Then the CSS would be:

```
.showmeonhover { display: none; }
.alwaysshowme:hover .showmeonhover {
    display: inline;
}
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Niffler/d2kYq/

Comment: Nice trick! ...but not very modular. I still would go with JQuery.

Comment: Maybe I could modify my 3 divs in that section and put them all into one large div. Would your way be do-able with two different hover elements? Hover over the left side of the div, displaying text in the upper center while hovering over the right side of the div, displying alternative text in the bottom center of the div.

Comment: @Niffler Option 2 is pretty cool. I think I will try to make that work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use JQuery, with hover : http://api.jquery.com/hover/ Look for the demo.

Comment: *"I would like to know if it's possible by using **CSS** to show text when mousing over a DIV or IMG or A tag."*

Comment: I don't think CSS is the **correct way** to do it. He's going to get stuck at some point, and pollute his CSS with logic that belongs to DOM manipulation.

Comment: Also, without flexbox/absolute positioning this is impossible (since `.image2` occurs *after* the span element.

Comment: My DIVs are displayed with absolute positions actually. They are inside one big DIV that centers them all in my page.